# TeraTerm での ssh 接続先の Vim で ctrl-^ が効かない（ctrl-6, alternate-file）

Tags: vim

vimでCtrl-^ ができる場合とできない場合があり、何が違うのか気になっています。

Windows Terminalでsshした先でvimを実行すると ctrl-^ が動作して代替ファイルが開くのですが、TeraTermでsshした先でvimを実行すると何も起きません。ctrl-6は動作します。

vimのせいではなく、端末のせいのようだなというところまでは分かったのですが、何が違うのか、TeraTermでもctrl-^ができる方法があるのか、気になっています。

ご存じの方がいたら教えてほしいです。

環境問わず `:e#` が可能なのもわかりましたが、押しにくい。

（追記）
Windows Terminal では ctrl-6 もできています。

Comment: 例えば`:nnoremap <Space><Space> <C-^>`みたいに別のキーに`map`してそちらを試すとどうなりますか？　TeraTermで接続するとキーボードレイアウトが"接続元のものから変わってしまう"か"接続元のものから変わっていることを期待しているのに変わっていない"かが起こっているかもしれません。

Comment: そうするとスペースキー2回でctrl-^の動きをしました。TeraTermが何かしているのが問題で、ctrl-^がvimにちゃんと伝わればできるはずというところでしょうか。

Comment: Windowsのコマンドプロンプト、PowerShellでsshコマンドを使って外部のサーバーにsshしてvimを実行すると、ctrl-^もctrl-6も効かず、ctrl-shift-6 が効きました。どれが普通だと思えばよいのか、もやもやします。

Comment: ssh先のvimまで<Ctrl-^>が届いていないように見えます。TeraTermの何らかのキーボードショートカットとして使用されていませんか？